# JQuery Validator lost tooltip layout

Tags: jquery, css, html, validation

I started using Jquery Validator.
I am not able to display the tooltips in my form, I was wondering if I have a Z index problem or if I've missed some code.

Below is a picture of my form, the returned error for the incorrect fields is red text on the blue background.  The form is mounted on a Fixed 'blue popup' Div and a background Div (the opacity grey).  The Z-index's are random 221 and 222 and the crosshair on the top right is 9999.  They were random numbers.  I'm not sure the Z-index is my problem yet, or if its CSS, my JS file form the Validator seems to be working ok as the boxes are red until the inputs are corrected.  The final object I haven't mentioned is a JQuery UI date picker on the dob (this is working correctly).

[image]
The file I stripped down to learn looks like below:

[image]

In the picture above the error is returned back into a 'tooltip' style box.

I'm hoping someone with Jquery Validator experience knows if I have messed my code up or if I have a Z-index problem, and its hiding behind my div.  My form does not have LABELS like the example, when I added a couple and matched the names/id's there was no difference.  The form is split into many divs as it displays differently on different media screens.

The FORM code attached:

```css
form.webmailRegisterForm label.error,
label.error {
  /* remove the next line when you have trouble in IE6 with labels in list */
  color: red;
  font-style: italic
}

div.error {
  display: none;
  background-color: #F79FB2;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #24058C;
  background: #fee3ad;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "desyrel", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

input.checkbox {
  border: none
}

input:focus {
  border: 2px dotted black;
}

input.error {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #FF87A8;
}
```

```html
<div class="registerTipBox" id="registerLongTitle">
  <h2>Coles Mail Registration</h2>
  <h3>providing a personal and customisable mailbox, contacts and calander.</h3>
</div>
<div id="registerContent">
  <hr>
  <div class="popupFormArea">
    <form action="" method="post" id="webmailRegisterForm" novalidate="novalidate">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="popupTitleCell">
          <h3>Name:</h3><label for="webmailFullName">Blah</label></div>
        <div class="popupInputCell">
          <input type="text" name="webmailFullName" id="webmailFullName" 
          class="popupInputField"></div>
        <div class="popupSpacer2">
          <p>Your Full Name (ex. John Coles)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="popupTitleCell">
          <h3>UserName:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="popupInputCell">
          <input type="text" name="webmailUserName" id="webmailUserName" 
          value="@allcoles.com" class="popupInputField"></div>
        <div class="popupSpacer2">
          <p>Preference email (ex john@allcoles.com)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="popupSpacer">
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="popupTitleCell">
          <h3>Existing Email:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="popupInputCell">
          <input type="text" name="webmailExEmail" id=name="webmailExEmail" 
          class="popupInputField"></div>
        <div class="popupSpacer2">
          <p>REQUIRED to recieve SignIn details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="popupTitleCell">
          <h3>Phone Number:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="popupInputCell">
          <input type="text" name="webmailPhone" id="webmailPhone" 
          class="popupInputField"></div>
        <div class="popupSpacer2">
          <p>(allows for SMS confirmation)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="popupTitleCell">
          <h3>Date of Birth:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="popupInputCell">
          <input type="text" id="datepickerRegister" name="webmailDOB"></div>
        <div class="popupSpacer2">
          <p>Select your DOB from the calender</p>
        </div>
        <div class="popupSpacer">
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="popupButtonCell">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated, references to code most welcome, and experience with a similar problem would be great.  Unfortunately I could not find a lot which I understand on over posts or Google.

The site live example is on [www.allcoles.com](https://www.allcoles.com).

Comment: Even more welcome would be a live example …

Comment: www.allcoles.com.  If you Click the register under the webmail button, I've removed the php stuff so you can fill the form in and see the jquery validator problem